# How do i fix the getting null location value from FusedLocationProviderClient in android

Tags: android, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

I have been trying to get current location data using FusedLocationProviderClient in android. I always get null on the location variable, How do i fix it?

I have tried to follow the steps from android developer website for FusedLocationProviderClient, It didn't help.

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Location permission Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    mLocation = location;
                    Log.d(TAG, "getLocation: "+mLocation.getLatitude()+","+mLocation.getLongitude());

                }

                    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                    locationRequest.setInterval(20 * 1000);
                    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                            if (locationResult == null) {
                                return;
                            } else {
                                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                                    if (location != null) {
                                        mLocation = location;
                                        Log.d(TAG, "getLocation: "+mLocation.getLatitude()+","+mLocation.getLongitude());

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Location Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                }}
        });
```

I expect this code to return current location data.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to fix, this is expected behavior.  getLastLocation returns the last location IF THE SYSTEM KNOWS IT.  It almost never knows it.  So it will almost always return null.  If you want to get an assured location, use requestLocationUpdates.  But you can never rely on getLastLocation working, and even when it does the data may be old.  It should really only be used in very limited circumstances.

Comment: Sir, i removed the lastlocation part from code, but i still get null at location variable

Answer (score 0):

The `getLastLocation()` returns null if the `Android System` doesn't have a knowledge about its last location.To provide last location to the `System` you can try one of the following things:

1. Before opening your app, open **Google Maps** and let the device get the current 
   location.After that you can return to your app.
2. The `Location` service in `Android` provide 3 modes.Check-up the **High 
   Accuracy** mode. Go to **Setting -> Location -> High Accuracy Mode**.